# Puppeteer Extra Plugin Stealth not find module when running on .exe file by Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer, electron-builder

I successfully use puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth in dev env when opening a browser with npm start, but when i run my app after running npm run package it showed that my stealth module not find.
"Cannot find module 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/chrome.app'"

Below is my code.

```
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from 'puppeteer';
import PuppeteerExtra from 'puppeteer-extra';
import PluginStealth from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import fs from 'fs';

const chromePaths = require('chrome-paths');
PuppeteerExtra.use(PluginStealth());

const myBrowser: MyBrowser = {
  newBrowser: async (): Promise<Browser> => {
    const browser = await PuppeteerExtra.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: chromePaths.chrome,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [`--window-size=1400,1000`, `--mute-audio`],
      defaultViewport: {
        width: 1400,
        height: 800,
      },
    });
    return browser;
  },
}
```

In package.json file i also add

```
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": ["node_modules/puppeteer/lib/*.js", "node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/**/*.js"]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding options in the webpack configuration file

```json
{
  externals: {
    "puppeteer": "XX",
    "puppeteer-extra": "XX",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "XX"
  }
}
```